# Azure DevOps Why can't my 'Add Tests' appear on my Kanban Features card

Tags: azure-devops

On the Azure DevOps Kanban board, the 'Add Test' link doesn't appear on the Features card even though it appears on the Product Backlog Item and the user story cards. It's even enabled in 'Annotations' in 'Configure team settings'. How do I get the 'Add Test' link on the Features card, even when it's enabled in 'Annotations'???

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not enable the **Test Annotations** for **Features** cards.

1,Click the **drop down** list on the Kanban Boards to switch to **Features** cards. See below:

[image]

2, After it is switched to Feature cards-->Click the Gear icon-->Annotations->Enable Test Annotation

[image]

3, Then you will see the **Add Test** link appears in Feature cards

[image]

Comment: Everything works on my home computer, not the work one. They both have the Azure server 2019 1.1 edition. Also, the only entity it works on is the Backlog. It doesn't work for the Features, Epic, etc. Everything is identical on work and home laps. Everything is enabled. It's not visible on Features, Epic, user Stories

Comment: That's weird.  Did it happen to boards in all projects and organizations on your work laps?

Comment: It is weird. Even checked permissions. All good. We're just using Azure for this 1 company project/program. But it's on all the laps. So it's not hardware-specific. It should be a straight shot. You enable, it appears. But only on 'Backlog'. Even the 'Test Plans' link on the left only has 'Test plan' and 'Runs', missing 'Progress Report' and 'Load test'. My whole leadership team is baffled.

Comment: I meant you could create a test project/organzation to see if the issue exists on the new project/organzation

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I brought that up to leadership. Will keep u posted

Comment: FWIW .. I think this is probably a bug fix and/or undocumented feature in Azure DevOps 2020.  We are testing RC2 right now and on Server2020 code with the latest backup I see this option without changing anything.  Server 2020 RTW is supposed to be ready sometime in October, so maybe consider upgrading?